# Using sinon withArgs and then try to do a restore I get TypeError: 'restore' is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stubbing

If I stub my function like so:

```
const sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
getInfoStub = sandbox.stub(ytdl, 'getInfo').withArgs(videoUrl).resolves(videoInfo);
```

And then I try to do getInfoStub.restore() I get a `TypeError: getInfoStub.restore is not a function`

However when I remove the option `.withArgs(videoUrl)` `restore` works fine:

```
const sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
getInfoStub = sandbox.stub(ytdl, 'getInfo').resolves(videoInfo);
```

What's the deal with `withArgs` that breaks sinon ?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
 const getInfoStub = sandbox.stub(ytdl, 'getInfo');
 const result = getInfoStub.withArgs(videoUrl).resolves(videoInfo);
 getInfoStub.restore();
```

Ref Link: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/